# how to draw this area involves huge number

Tags: plotting

i see this from the website.

https://www.zhihu.com/question/29868843/answer/468030160

[image]

with $0≤x≤106,n≤y≤n+17$ , which $n=4858450636189713423582095962494202044581400587983244549483093085061934704708809928450644769865524364849997247024915119110411605739177407856919754326571855442057210445735883681829823754139634338225199452191651284348332905131193199953502413758765239264874613394906870130562295813219481113685339535565290850023875092856892694555974281546386510730049106723058933586052544096664351265349363643957125565695936815184334857605266940161251266951421550539554519153785457525756590740540157929001765967965480064427829131488548259914721248506352686630476300$

will get[image]

i want to draw it in mathematica,but since the n is too big to plot.Is there some ways to draw it?

```
RegionPlot[
 1/2 < Floor[
   Mod[Floor[y/17] 2^(-17 Floor[x] - Mod[Floor[y], 17]), 2]], {x, 0, 
  106}, {y, n, n + 17}]
```

```
n->4858450636189713423582095962494202044581400587983244549483093085061934704708809928450644769865524364849997247024915119110411605739177407856919754326571855442057210445735883681829823754139634338225199452191651284348332905131193199953502413758765239264874613394906870130562295813219481113685339535565290850023875092856892694555974281546386510730049106723058933586052544096664351265349363643957125565695936815184334857605266940161251266951421550539554519153785457525756590740540157929001765967965480064427829131488548259914721248506352686630476300
```

Comment: For searching purposes: [Tupper's Self-Referential Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TuppersSelf-ReferentialFormula.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Table[1/2 < Floor[Mod[Floor[y/17] 2^(-17 Floor[x] - Mod[Floor[y], 17]), 2]], 
      {x, 0, 106}, {y, n, n + 16}]\[Transpose] // Reverse // Boole // ArrayPlot
```

[image]

Note the `n + 17` is modified to `n + 16`.

Comment: send you this code :-)   `Table[1/2 < 
       Floor[Mod[Floor[y/5] 2^(-5 Floor[x] - Mod[Floor[y], 5]), 
         2]], {x, 0, 13}, {y, n, n + 4}]\[Transpose] /. 
    n -> 179057560799192115125. // Reverse // Boole // ArrayPlot`

Comment: here is the theory under the formula.
https://www.zhihu.com/question/35867114/answer/64865516  here is some code to generate the huge number 
https://www.zhihu.com/question/22506052/answer/255277333